# Unable to install app from Sharepoint Store into Sharepoint 2016

Tags: error, sharepoint-store

I reinstalled my company's SharePoint with the latest SharePoint 2016.

I have gotten the SharePoint Store working, able to install 2 to 3 apps.

Now I receive this message:

> Everything is fine, but we had a small problem getting your license. Please go back to the SharePoint Store to get this app again and you won't be charged for it.
>
> If 'Retry' doesn't work, return to your site and try again later.

What would be the reason?

Comment: are you using System account to add an app ? Also trying adding it from firefox or chrome or any other different browser.

Comment: yes, am using system account to add and am using IE 10 to add.

Answer (score 5):

I have faced the same problem today while adding an Add-In to a site.
[image]

As you can see in above pic, the same error is being displayed.

**Issue:** Everything is fine, but we had a small problem getting your license. Please go back to the SharePoint Store to get this app again and you won't be charged for it.

**Root Cause:** User is using System Account to Add the app in the site.

**Solution:** Try adding the app with a different account which is not a system account. Also, that particular account should be a SCA or must have Full Control on the site.